# JNA Library - Problems on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, transparency, jna, shapes

This is a question regarding the JNA library in a Java program.

I have a tray application.
"JFrame 1" is loaded at start of program.
"JFrame 1" has a custom shape and has transparency. (Custom shape = ellipse)
It works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

BUT!

When I open "JFrame 2" (a normal JFrame without custom shape and transparency), "JFrame 1" will lose it's custom shape and will show a normal undecorated frame. (A square)
This only happens on Mac OS X.

I've searched the internet, but no luck. Maybe you can help me.

Thanks,
Gianni

Comment: what happens when you open JFrame 2 and then JFrame 1?

Comment: That is not possible. "JFrame 1" is always open first, and cannot be closed.

Comment: Can you apply the styling such that you expect JFrame 1 to be undecorated and JFrame 2 to be decorated? (trying to come up with some debug information here)

Comment: Frame 1 is undecorated, frame 2 is decorated. 
As I said, it's working fine under Windows and Linux. But Mac OS X is giving problems. No errors are produced.

Comment: What's the JNA angle? It doesn't seem related to the question.